# How to find the average of multiple columns with different specific weights?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, average, weighted-average

I need to calculate the average of `Value_A`, `Value_B`, and `Value_C` in mssql.
My problem is that every information I need is in one row.

Every value has its own weight:

```
(sum of values * weight) / (sum weight):
```

Every column can be null. If there is a value but not a weight, weight is 100,
if there is a weight and no value then the specific value is not considered of course

e.g.

1st column:

```
(2*100+1*80)/(100+80)= 2.55  ≈ 2.6
```

2nd column:

```
(1*100+2*80)/(100+80)
```

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
| ID   | VALUE_A | VALUE_B | VALUE_C | Weight_A | Weight_B | Weight_C | AVG |
+------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
| 1111 | 2       | 1       | null    | 100      | 80       | 60       | 2.6 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
| 2222 | 1       | 2       | null    | 100      | 80       | 60       |     |
+------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
```

I got this far to get the AVG values without weights

```
select ID, VALUE_A, VALUE_B, VALUE_C, Weight_A, Weight_B, Weight_C,
        (SELECT AVG(Cast(c as decimal(18,1)))
        FROM   (VALUES(VALUE_A),
                      (VALUE_B),
                      (VALUE_C)) T (c)) AS [Average]
FROM table
```

Second try was selecting sum of values multiply them by their weights and then divide them by sum of the weights. Sum of weights is missing. Can't figure out how to add it

```
select *, 
    (SELECT SUM(Cast(c as decimal(18,1)))
    FROM   (VALUES(VALUE_A* ISNULL(Weight_A,100)),
                  (VALUE_B* ISNULL(Weight_B,100)),
                  (VALUE_C* ISNULL(Weight_C,100))

    ) T (c)) AS [Average]

FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT SUM(val * COALESCE(w, 100)) / SUM(w) as weighted_average,
       SUM(val * COALESCE(w, 100)) as weighted_sum
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (t.VALUE_A, t.Weight_A),
             (t.VALUE_B, t.Weight_B),
             (t.VALUE_C, t.Weight_C)
     ) a(val, w)
WHERE a.val IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Does this exclude the weight from `SUM(w)` if the Val is null?  looking at the second EG above `(1*100+2*80)/(100+80)` it looks like OP wants that behavior.

Comment: @DanielE. . . . Yes, I see that in the question now.  This is readily handled with a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Average could be calculated

```
    SELECT *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN (W.weight_A + W.Weight_B+ W.Weight_C) = 0
                THEN 0
            ELSE (ISNULL(VALUE_A, 0 * W.Weight_A)
                  + (ISNULL(VALUE_B, 0) * W.Weight_B) 
                  + (ISNULL(VALUE_C, 0) * W.Weight_C)) 
                  / (W.weight_A + w.Weight_B+ W.Weight_C)
            END Average
FROM TABLE t
CROSS APPLY (Select CASE WHEN VALUE_A is null then 0 ELSE ISNULL(Weight_A,100) END [Weight_A]
            ,CASE WHEN VALUE_B is null then 0 ELSE ISNULL(Weight_B,100) END [Weight_B]
            ,CASE WHEN VALUE_C is null then 0 ELSE ISNULL(Weight_C,100) END [Weight_C]) W
```